# Disabling WinAPI

Tags: c, winapi, dll

I'm building a game where each player must program his bot. The key idea is that the player will program in C (or C++, or whatever compatible language), build a DLL and send this DLL to the server, so that no one can get his code. The problem is: how to make sure that he is not calling any illegal function? Like creating files or opening a socket. The DLL will be loaded with LoadLibrary and a function will be called. All interaction will happen with callback functions. A possible solution would be placing a empty kernel32.dll (and others) so that all winapi calls will fail. Is this safe and works on every case? Is there a better way to do it?

Please note that the player thread (the one how called the dll) must still be able to comunicate with the game, maybe with an open socket. On Linux this can be easily done with [`seccomp`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seccomp).

Comment: Have you thought about scripting engines?

Comment: This would be an option. But still wanna know if it's possible with C. As I can do it on Linux, I was expecting Windows to be able to do something similar.

Comment: Google does it in Chrome with Native Client (NaCl). Not easy...

Comment: [Detours](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/project/detours/) - Binary Interception of Win32 Functions

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This will not work without either fully analyzing all DLLs prior to loading them (which is basically impossible), or creating some sort of magic on the same level as `seccomp`. Given any measures you take to restrict their access, such as creating a dummy `kernel32.dll`, the user-submitted DLL can take countermeasures, such as loading DLLs you didn't consider, calling DLLs which were loaded by the host process (possibly via functions in the host application!), or submitting Windows system calls directly.

One option may be making use of the Windows security token functionality which Google Chrome uses to "sandbox" web renderer processes. This is *incredibly* arcane stuff, though, and it involves running the DLL in a separate process anyway. If you're still interested, you may want to read [the Windows Chrome sandbox design documents](http://dev.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/sandbox). Keep in mind, though, that Google has spent an lot of development time getting the sandbox "right", and yet there have still been a couple of high-profile compromises -- the chances that you will be able to do the same on your own are slim, especially without extensive previous experience with Windows security.

Answer (score 11):

Your best bet is to create a user with reduced privileges, which will allow you to control file access quite easily, and run the bot code in a sub-process running as that user.

If you also want to restrict network connections, it is also easy to setup a firewall so that the aforementionned process does not have the right to connect to external hosts.

If you need more control over which API calls you allow or not, there is a technique called 'API Interception via DLL Redirection' which is explained for example here:

```
http://109.163.225.194/download/files/other/DLL_Redirection_en.pdf
```

(found via google)

Comment: Using the API interception to disable all functions is very hard, but using a very limited user account could be the way to go!

Comment: I cant access that link, but DLL redirection will not help you as a coder can just do the system calls himself.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe my answer will not be very helpful but i think using DLL or any other executable that contains machine code is unsafe, even if it is being ran as limited user or even in virtual machine it still opens attack vectors. First thing that comes to mind is to use off the shelf interpreter and use it to compile your own bytecode. However if you insist on using DLL, you can edit DLL import address table and ditch unwanted functions. As complex as this sounds there is [library for this](https://www.reversinglabs.com/open-source/titanengine.html)

Answer (score 0):

A local firewall may solve the networking aspect - but I see no simple bulletproof solution for the other parts of your question.
I also believe that placing an "empty" kernel32 and ntdll may cause some serious issues for many legit processes.